# onOptionsItemSelected not called for Up button in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am adding a Up button to my Android application. The app's minimum SDK is 14, and I am testing it with an HTC phone on SDK version 15.

The activity is a subclass of android.app.Activity (not ActionBarActivity from the support package).

ActionBar style display options includes the homeAsUp flag, and I am able to see the standard arrow. However, clicking on the logo does nothing.

I have connected the debugger, and I am able to see that the onOptionsItemSelected method is not called at all. This cannot be because of misspelt name, because other menu items (e.g., Settings) do work (and I can see in the debugger that onOptionsItemSelected method gets called).

The parentActivityName and meta-data PARENT_ACTIVITY are set correctly (although I believe this would only matter if the method got called).

Is there anything I am missing? And how do I get the up button to work?

Comment: It seems that a custom theme interferes with the availability of the Up button. I removed the custom theme from this activity, and the button is working.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue "onOptionsItemSelected" not called when using the ActionBarDrawerToggle it seems like the solution is setting this listener - it is called when the Up button is clicked.

```
drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish(); // or any other code you want to run here
    }
});
```